# How do I generate combinations based on column values in SQL? (Is this even possible?)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a new column in a table whose contents are based off values of an existing pair of columns. 
Specifically if I have table like(ID is not the primary key)

```
ID   |   Value  |   New Column(The column I want)
1         A           A:apple
1         B           A:orange
2        apple        B:apple
2        orange       B:orange
```

Im a novice to SQL, so any insight here would be really helpful.

Btw, Im using Oracle if that matters.

Additional Details: Im looking to pair Values:Values based on the fact that their ID's dont match

Comment: Your question doesn't quite seem to match the table schema you've given. You say that you want to base values off a pair of columns, but your new column appears to pull from two rows, not two columns. Are you looking for 1:apple or A:apple? If the first, look into Computed columns, if the second, please give me detail on what causes a row to match another row

Comment: what is the critera to join them? that their IDs aren't equal. Could you have  A:B or apple:orange

Comment: Added info in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want all values for ID1 paired up with all values for ID2, you can cross-join the table to itself, but filtered on ID:

```
select t1.value ||':'|| t2.value
from my_table t1
cross join my_table t2
where t1.id = 1
and t2.id = 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60b3a/1).

Comment: Thanks! A followup :Can this be applied to any number of rows? For e.g if there were an  id 3. then `select t1.value ||':'|| t2.value||':'|| t3.value
from my_table t1
cross join my_table t2
where t1.id = 1
and t2.id = 2
cross join my_table t3
where t1.id = 1
and t3.id = 3;` Would this be right?

Comment: @KodeSeeker - yes, sort of, but you can't have join conditions in a cross join. And the number of combinations grows rapidly. If you want all combinations of all three sets of values then yes, that's roughly how you'd do it. [Another fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de27c/3).

Answer (score 2):

SQL fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8b4a/3)

```
select t1.value||':'||t2.value
from mytable t1
cross join
mytable t2
where t1.id = 1
and t2.id = 2
```